# Git based automatic versioning in Gradle

Tags: java, git, gradle, groovy, versioning

I'd like to implement automatic versioning for java-projects in Gradle via Git tags. Currently I'm using the git describe command to generate a version string. The version string has to be used in a manifest-file and also be programmatically retrievable. This is why I implemented a method to save it in a properties file that get's included in the build and can be read by Java code.

What I currently have is this small Gradle plugin (I'm really new to gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: VersioningPlugin

class VersioningPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private Project project;

    private String getVersion() {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        project.exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        stdout.toString().trim()
    }

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        this.project = project

        project.extensions.create('versioning', VersioningPluginExtension)

        project.versioning.version = getVersion()

        project.task('writeVersionFile') {
            doLast {
                def versionPropsFile = project.versioning.versionFile
                def versionProps = new Properties()
                versionProps.put('version', getVersion())
                versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
            }
        }
    }
}

class VersioningPluginExtension {
    File versionFile
    String version
}

compileJava.dependsOn writeVersionFile
```

I use it in my build scrips like this:

```
apply from: 'versioning.gradle'
versioning {
  versionFile = file('my/ressource/folder/version.properties')
}
println(versioning.version)
```

Everything works OK. The only problem I have is the following: I use gradle to build and test my code, then commit the code and create a git tag. If I now ask gradle to package a jar file without cleaning first, it doesn't copy the new version.properties into the jar file because it didn't notice that the file changed. So my application shows the old version.

Is there anything I can do about this? How can I get gradle to notice the version change and create a jar with the current `version.properties` file?

Comment: Looks like you need to either make your plugin update the `project.version` property or change the jar name when it is written.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to configure a `TaskOutputs` (or `from`) for `Jar` task so that it can recognize if something has changed and be run without calling `clean` explicitly. This can be done in the following way:

```
jar {
  from versioning.versionFile
}
```

Secondly. You can configure `writeVersionFile` in a similar way. If you configure both inputs and outputs the task will be *cacheable*. How it has changed can been seen [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/blob/master/43074676/versioning.gradle), a demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/43074676).

Also, mind that your task is created now in `afterEvaluate` closure. Why is that? Because this is after `versioning {}` extension is executed and `versionFile` property is set and can be configured as an output.

You can also configure `jar` input in `versioning.gradle` file.